# Compiling kiss fft with float and double support in the same app

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, kissfft

I'm trying to get kiss fft to compile both float and double implementations in the same app using visual studio 2013.  I see that all I need to do is set the kiss_fft_scalar to double and re-compile to get double.

To this end I put together a header whereby I include the headers with kiss_fft_scalar changed inside 2 different namespaces as follows:

```
namespace KissFloat
{
    #undef KISS_FFT_H
    #undef KISS_FTR_H
    #define kiss_fft_scalar float
    #include "kiss_fft.h"
    #include "tools/kiss_fftr.h"
};

namespace KissDouble
{
    #undef KISS_FFT_H
    #undef KISS_FTR_H
    #define kiss_fft_scalar double
    #include "kiss_fft.h"
    #include "tools/kiss_fftr.h"
};
```

I can't however figure out how to include the cpp code.  I've tried a seperate KissFloat and KissDouble file. I've then tried a few things in the cpp file but everything I try ends up with compile errors.  usually relating to struct redefinition.

Can anyone think of a way to make this work?  Or am I just better off re-writing kiss fft using templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've discovered that Eigen has done the work of templating kiss FFT for me.  Yay to other people doing the hard work! ;)

Eigen is available here:

https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src

and the kiss fft implementation is under

"unsupported/Eigen/src/FFT/"

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea, but you might have better luck just hacking on the files e.g. making `kiss_fft_scalar` a template parameter.   One problem is that the header files will be including other header files like `stdlib.h`.  I suppose you could pre-emptively include those files before you do your namespace trick.

I'm guessing the struct redef errors are for the `kiss_fft_state` in `_kiss_fft_guts.h`?
It might work if you have separate Float/Double .cpp files and *using* directives before inclusion of the .c files.

If you decide to templatize it, you could take a look at the  [Eigen (partial) c++ port of kissfft.](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/ef6d89748176edf76e75b2c06805fe374672bd00/unsupported/Eigen/src/FFT/ei_kissfft_impl.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: Thanks for the response ... and yeah .. I have tried the using statements.  Had the same thought myself :)  Sadly it didn't work :(  You are right on the struct redef errors ... good idea on the pre including the headers!